# Cant trigger segue when selecting a table view cell (at once)

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a todo list app and have two View Controllers and I have to pass the Index Path of the selected row from the `CategoryViewController` to `ItemsViewController` and trigger the Segue...
[This Is my Category View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAe6i.png)

But when I Click one of the cell, it is just being selected but the segue is not triggered
[Heres How](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekv0M.png)
But the segue is triggered when I select another Cell after selecting First one...Here's My code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToItems", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("sucess")

    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ToDoListViewControlorer
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        destinationVC.selectedCategory = categoriesArray[indexPath.row]

    }

}
```

Comment: is not `didDeselectRowAt` its `didSelectRowAt`

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, override `didSelectRowAt` method, because you want to handle moment when user select row, not deselect. Also as `sender` pass selected item

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToItems", sender: categoriesArray[indexPath.row]) 
}
```

and then in `prepare(for:sender:)` just downcast sender

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ToDoListViewControlorer {
        destinationVC.selectedCategory = sender as! Category
    }
}
```

*p.s. name your controller `Controller`, not `Controlorer`*

Answer (score 0):

Send your `indexPath.row` in sender `argument` of `performSegue`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "youridentifier", sender: indexPath.row)
}
```

get `indexPath.row` from the sender argument and pass to `ToDoListViewControlorer`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("sucess")

    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ToDoListViewControlorer
    if let indexPathRow = sender as? Int {
        destinationVC.selectedCategory = categoriesArray[indexPathRow]

    }

}
```